# Drupal 7 main-menu - change item text if user logged in

Tags: 7, routes

I'm using Drupal 7's 'main-menu' to run my site's navigation. In my design, the links to join and sign in are in the main nav.

My join link goes to `/user/register` so it vanishes when a user is logged in. But my sign in is just `/user`, so that still shows up when a user is logged in. I want it to be replaced, or at least change the text to something like 'My Profile' instead of 'sign in'.

Ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Drupal 7 comes with a user menu as well, that contains these links that change automatically when logged in or not. Edit the user menu items and move them to the main menu.

Comment: This seemed promising, but the 'my account' link, after moving it to the main-menu, seems to carry a 'Request new password' sub-item that I can't seem to find anywhere in the UI to disable. I really do not want that as it renders as a dropdown beneath 'my account' which makes no sense (why would you need a new password if you were able to log in). :( Any ideas?

Comment: Well, for some reason this has vanished, so nevermind...

Answer (score 2):

change the sign in link to /user/login.   It will now vanish when the user logs in.   As for replacing it you would need to write some custom code

Comment: Thanks, this helped, and combined with Nigel's advice, I'm all set.