# How to alter main_menu for logged user?

Tags: routes, navigation

I would like to alter/change structure of *main menu* links (programmatically!) for logged in users. What is the simplest way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I hope, [Drupal 7 main-menu - change item text if user logged in](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/7020/drupal-7-main-menu-change-item-text-if-user-logged-in) you check this first.

If this does not complete your requirement, then, u have to override the `theme_menu_link` hook.

http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!menu.inc/function/theme_menu_link/7

You can check whether the user is logged in or not by checking **boolean** `$logged_in`. If it is true, user is logged in else not.

Comment: i hope the second link will help me. Basically, i want to create a new menu for every user that is logged in.

Comment: yeah, then you override that hook to get what you need. :-)

Comment: I don't think this is the best way to create a new menu. Here you can check one link at a time, but it would be better to create whole menu at the same time. Wouldn't it?